# Usage of two different same kind of beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a service which uses OAuth2RestTemplate bean to communicate with other oauth enabled services. This bean uses client_id_A and client_secret_B.

I have written an app to validate the user credentials with an action when accessing a resource. This app also has a OAuth2RestTemplate bean with client_id_B and client_secret_b. I have given this bean a name restTemplateB and used @Qualifier("restTemplateB").

Two apps are working fine when they run as two different apps.

Now I am building second app as a jar and using it in the first app to the validation and getting the following exception

```
" No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: restTemplate, restTemplateB"
```

As I want to distribute app B to other teams and make it used in multiple services, I don't want them to name their bean(restTemplateA) and add @Qualifier where ever they use.

I don't want let other services change their when they use my service. Any suggestions how to overcome this

Comment: You could add a `@Profile("mine")` into restTemplateB, enable the profile in your application, and by default the profile will not include `mine` and not load that bean.

Comment: It didn't help. I am loading restTemplateB configuration into App A's context and it is creating both beans and make them available in App A

Comment: Did you enable the profile as well? It needs the active profile to activate the bean.

Comment: Yes before enabling I got bean creation exception. When I enabled the profile it has two beans and spring couldn't understand which one to use(I have updated previous comment)

Comment: Before enabling, could it not find any beans? And afterwards it found two beans? That shouldn't be the case. You can also annotate one profile as "!mine" and the other as "mine" if you own both templates.

Comment: I do not want to change the client app( App A) code because if I do all services that will use App B has to change their code or atleast add this propery( I may do that if I do not have any other option)